# Why doesn't Createfile() have a binary flag

Tags: c++, winapi

One of the great joys of windows programming is remembering to put 'wb' or 'rb' or ios::binary in all the file open calls so that Windows doesn't merrily convert all your 0x13s.

I just had to convert a bunch of nicely standard code to use Createfile() to get a certain flag - and it occurred to me that there is no way to specify binary.
How does it know? I really don't want it changing bytes in my MP4 stream thank-you-very-much.

Comment: I just can't understand the question. The files are opened in binary mode, so no CR\LF gets changed.

Comment: Didn't realise it always opened in binary mode. Since binary mode is a window sonly feature and CreateFile is a windows only version of FILE it seemed logical that it would do this windows only function - or at least mention it in the docs

Comment: Text mode isn't a Windows only feature: it's needed on any machine that doesn't use a single LF to terminate lines.  Pre-X Macs for example, and I've heard some file types on VAX were/are treated more as a table, with lines representing rows, and the whole thing stored very differently from "text" files — but much better for DB-like use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because CreateFile doesn't do "text-mode"/newline conversions.  Those are handled at a higher level, either in FILE for the CRT or iostreams for C++.

Comment: Never really thought of Createfile as a lower level FILE, just as a windows only equivalent. I suppose to MS everything is Windows so you write cr/lf and read cr/lf, no need to ever convert.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: actually, the `CreateFile()` function is just poorly named. It is used to open many, many other types of resources (folders, drives, serial/parallel ports, etc.), for most of which text/binary doesn't make sense because you're not transferring text.

Comment: CreateFile is the user-mode interface to the ZwCreateFile kernel function, so it's as low-level as you can get in user-mode.

Comment: Actually I misspoke there... NtCreateFile is the user-mode interface to ZwCreateFile, and CreateFile calls NtCreateFile. So you could go a little lower than CreateFile by calling NtCreateFile directly, but it's somewhat uglier.

Answer (score 7):

Everything is binary as far as the Windows API is concerned. Personally I prefer it that way. I never use the "text mode" in the standard library stuff.

Comment: +1: I totally agree. Especially that many higher-level tools filter CR/LF only when they know you're reading text. For instance, the `<iostream>` standard library filters then out when using `operator>>` with `std::string` but not when using the `get(char*,streamsize)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify a binary or text flag, because to the Windows OS, all files are binary! The wb and rb options are introduced as a nicety, as part of the C IO stream functionality, and even then only on DOS / Windows, to help the developer read and write text files and perform CR/LF to LF conversion.