# The write function in fstream will cause bug on Windows 10

Tags: c++, system

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream outfile("datafile.txt", ios::out);
    char colorArry[1024];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        colorArry[i * 4] = i&0xff;
        colorArry[i * 4 + 1] = i&0xff;
        colorArry[i * 4 + 2] = i&0xff;
        colorArry[i * 4 + 3] = 0b00000000;
    }
    outfile.write(colorArry, 1024);
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

There is something wrong when I run this code on my Windows 10. As it shows in the picture, it goes wrong when i is 10. Which should be 0A 0A 0A 00 rather than
0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 00.
[the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRd8u.png)

Comment: Open the file in `ios::binary` mode.

Comment: And I agree wholeheartedly that this is a bug in Windows 10. A bug that will never get fixed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  In fact, this is not because I opened in the wrong way. This code runs well on Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: @chuang `fstream outfile("datafile.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  It seems working. I will take more test later. Thank you a lot.

Comment: That's because Linux does not have the Microsoft Windows bug. The Microsoft Windows bug requires files to be opened in binary mode, in order to avoid the library from writing `0x0D` every time your code writes `0x0A`. This is not the only Microsoft Windows bug, and the only way to avoid dealing with Microsoft Windows bugs is to continue to use Linux (Ubuntu, or any other distribution).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks! I now use Linux more than Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are correct but they don't explain:

- Windows convention is to use CR + LF combination to represent the end of line  (encoded as 0x0D and 0x0A).
- C++ uses `\n` to represent a new line, which Visual C++ encodes as 0x0A. (Additionally, Visual C++ encodes `\r` as `0x0D`)
- To allow writing portable code, `fstream` will automatically convert end of line representations. That means, when opened in text mode, every time you write a C++ `\n` end of line, it will write the CR+LF = `0x0D` `0x0A` sequence into the file.
- `fstream` also converts on reading, in the opposite direction.

You can fix it by passing the `ios::binary` option to fstream, telling it your data is binary and not text, so it must not do that substitution::

```
std::ofstream file("path/to/file", ios::binary);
```

Linux is not affected, because it uses just LF (0x0A) to represent an end of line, and Linux compilers consistently encode `\n` as `0x0A` too. Therefore, `fstream` does no substitution. That's why you don't have the issue when you run your code on Linux.

Comment: I believe it's actually the underlying OS stuff that performs the translation, not `fstream` - `fstream` translates and passes through your flags.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hmmm it's a good question. I believe it uses [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) under the hood. If that's correct, CreateFile does not have binary/text differenciation.

Comment: Huh, seems you're right! https://stackoverflow.com/a/4054721/560648

Comment: Yup, under Windows it's the console which has the text/raw distinction. See `SetConsoleMode`, in particular `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT`. And with processed output, `\n` translates to a `SetConsoleCursorPosition( )` call.