# How to disable linefeed correction when using MSDN SerialPort or CreateFile to read/write from a USB-RS232 SerialPort connection?

Tags: c++, msdn, serial-communication

Is there a way to disable line-feed conversions when reading from a SerialPort on MSDN (VC++)  when the COM port is actually a USB-to-RS-232 cable ? I  can read and write using CreateFile (VC++) when the devices are connected by a simple serial cable but when I use the USB-to-RS-232, all of th e line-feeds are converted to CR/LF.  I would prefer to stick to CreateFile (Win32, C++) instead of SerialPort (CLR,C++) if possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: CreateFile doesn't seem to do so, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054695/why-doesnt-createfile-have-a-binary-flag). Are you sure the conversion is not already done on sender side?

Comment: Read bytes instead of text, SerialPort::Read() instead of SerialPort::ReadLine/Existing()

Comment: Hi, I Read() instead , but no luck.  Thanks though.

Comment: Aconcagua : I read that post as well.  The Sender is not applying the conversion.  Perhaps the USB-RS232 driver (Prolific) is.  Maybe I need to write my own USB-RS232 driver (hope not!).  Thanks